# JMockit expectations API - return input parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I know that if I want to mock a method and assign a specific behavior to it based on its input, I can do it with the MockUps API:

```
public class DuplicationTest {

    static class Duplicator {
        public String duplicate(String str) { return null; }
    }

    @Test
    public void verifySameStringReturnedWithMockupsAPI() throws Exception {
        new MockUp<Duplicator>() {
            @Mock public String duplicate(String str) { return str; }
        };

        Duplicator dup = new Duplicator();
        assertEquals("test", dup.duplicate("test"));
    }
}
```

This test passes.
However, sometimes I don't have the luxury of working with the MockUps API (e.g. when mocking static classes), therefore I can only use the Expectations API:

```
@Test
public void verifySameStringReturnedWithExpectationsAPI(@Mocked Duplicator dup) throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {{
        dup.duplicate(anyString); result = anyString;
    }};

    assertEquals("test", dup.duplicate("test"));
}
```

This obviously fails. The call to `dup.duplicate("test")` returns an empty `String` (probably some kind of default). Is there any way around it?

Comment: You cannot alter the behavior without mocking it. Your first example is completely redundant, is it just example code?

Comment: Yep, it's just example code, but why is it redundant? The real (fake) implementation returns null

Comment: Because you are not testing any production code. You are basically just testing that you mocked it correctly. It can never fail, no matter what changes you make to production code.

Comment: Yes, you're right regarding that matter, but it's just there to prove a point. 10x for clearing that up

Comment: A `MockUp` can be used with a `static` nested class as well, but maybe you meant something else. With `Expectations`, a `Delegate` object that returns the received argument can be assigned to `result`. So, both APIs can do anything the other can, in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by a comment made by Rogério, I managed to solve the issue using a `Delegate`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Test
public void verifySameStringReturnedWithExpectationsAPI(@Mocked Duplicator dup) throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {{
        dup.duplicate(anyString);
        result = new Delegate<String>() { String delegate(String str) { return str; }};
    }};

    assertEquals("test", dup.duplicate("test"));
    assertEquals("delegate did it", dup.duplicate("delegate did it"));
}
```

This is not the most elegant solution and could look a lot better if the `Delegate` class was a `@FunctionalInterface` (which I understood would happen in the next major release of JMockit).
For now, that seems to be the only way to mock behavior according to the input parameters within the Expectations API.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, it returns an empty String because you are setting `result = anyString`. anyString is a jmockit object that is used to match any possible string value. What you want to do instead is set result to the value you actually want to return, in this case `result = "test"`.

Comment: I want the result to be the same value as the input, not "test" in particular

Comment: In that case, I think you will need to use a MockUp (inline or otherwise). There's no mechanism that I know of in expectation blocks to capture and return the parameter value. You mentioned that you can't use a MockUp for a static class. I don't believe that's actually case, unless there's something about your version of jmockit I don't know about. I just wrote up a test mock for a static class using version 1.19.